# Logout error with OIDC connection (WSO2 4.1 & IS 5.11)

Tags: wso2, openid-connect, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have a common problem with my OIDC connection : I can't logout properly from my Devportal.
When I logout, an error shows up : "**ID token signature validation failed.**".
Also, I have this **log** on my Identity Server :

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oidc.session.servlet.OIDCLogoutServlet} - Error while getting service provider from the clientId. org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: ID token signature validation failed.
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oidc.session.servlet.OIDCLogoutServlet.getOpenIDConnectSkipUserConsent(OIDCLogoutServlet.java:796)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oidc.session.servlet.OIDCLogoutServlet.doGet(OIDCLogoutServlet.java:199)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:72)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:98)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

So I go back to the Devportal ihm and logout again and then, my account is disconnected.

To be clear, we configured an OIDC connection with a LDAP and it's working just fine.
About this connection, we have (1) an Identity Provider configured on the IAM, linked to (2) a Service Provider, which contacts (3) an Identity Provider configured on the IS and which refers to (4) the Service Provider of the LDAP.

We use : **WSO2 v4.1 and IS v5.11**

---

I found multiple solutions to a similar problem, but none of then worked for me. Here is a list of what I tried :

- I add a logout url to my callback url in my Service Provider :
  "https://:/oidc/logout" or "https://:/devportal/services/auth/callback/logout"
- I modify the <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml to add this configuration :
  `[oauth.oidc.id_token] sign_with_sp_key=true`
- I also modify the <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml to add the configuration :
  `[authentication] sign_auth_response_with_tenant_of= "sp" #user`
  And I checked "Use tenant domain in local subject identifier" inside "Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration" on my Service Provider.
- I added a link to the jwks certificate on the Identity Provider configured on the IAM
- on the Carbon IHM, inside the Identity Providers'Resident, I suppressed ports from Identity Provider Entity ID

Do you have any other ideas to correct this error ?